# fillFormula Issue using Exceljs

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I am using this code

```
worksheet.fillFormula('L2:L8', '=G2*O2', (row, col) => cellfielddata);
```

But this code show only last cell value in all of cell

[image]

I want export Excel file and fill the formula without change value
the Excel value should be same as grid value
After applying custom formula to the JS code, when we are exporting the Excel file, the Excel value should be same as grid value
After exporting Excel file show excel value as a grid value and Show formula if click F2
If any change is done in G2 : G....or O2: O......., then that change should show up in L2: L........